# Is it possible to create a SOAP web service in C/C++ over HTTP?

Tags: soap, cxf, apache-axis, gsoap, axis2c

Is it possible to create **SOAP web services** (not client) over **HTTP** in **C** or **C++**, that respects the **WSDL contract**, using these Frameworks/libraries  :

1. **Apache CXF**
2. **Axis2/c**
3. **gSOAP**

??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Apache CXF - No. It's written on Java and you can't write Web Services on C using CXF (JNI is not a good idea in this case).
2. Axis2/C - Yes! It's a Web service framework written on C. It's one of most powerful Web services frameworks for C. You can write Web services from scratch or generate it from WSDL. But it will be plain C and you may need to write extra code to start it working. To provide more convenient interface to Web services engine you may want to use some wrapper like WSO2 or Staff. For details please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624349/axis2c-unofficial-vs-axis2c-staff/18638798#18638798).
3. gSoap - yes. It's not trivial but possible.